# How do I not assign a new value and not return anything in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

```
{props.chat.last_message == null? props.chat.notext = '' : props.chat.last_message.text}
```

I dont need to assign a new value to the `.notext` and also not return anything if the `props.chat.last_message == null`. What should I do instead so that when there are no messages it returns nothing until the conversation is started in which it will show the last message only.

Comment: Maybe `props.chat.last_message?.text || ""` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
props.chat.last_message && props.chat.last_message.text
```

Comment: Thanks, but just curious is there any other way of doing this? And like how many ways can I use to achieve the same thing?